# Return the latest record which was before the current row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of messages. Each message has a timestamp `created_ts`, a type (either `purchase` or `support`), `user_id`,  and a primary key `msg_id`. E.g.,

| msg_id | user_id | created_ts | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | purchase |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | support |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | purchase |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | support |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | support |

I'd like to generate a table of support messages, such that each row will contain the details of the support message, and also the details of the last purchase (if such exists), i.e. the latest message of type `purchase`, that happened before this row's support message.   E.g.,

| support_msg_id | user_id | support_created_ts | type | last_purchase_msg_id | last_purchase_created_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | support | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | support | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | support | 3 | 3 |

I've tried the following query:

```
select * from
(select msg_id as support_msg_id, user_id, created_ts as support_created_ts, type
  (select msg_id as last_purchase_msg_id
   from messages
   where type = 'purchase' and created_ts < support_created_ts
 order by created_ts desc
limit 1)
  
 from messages
 where type = 'support'
) as supports
inner join
(
 select msg_id as last_purchase_msg_id, created_ts as last_purchase_ts
   from messages
   where type = 'purchase'
) as purchases
on supports.last_purchase_msg_id = purchases.last_purchase_msg_id
```

However this is too slow.

Comment: It appears {user_id, created_ts} are the natural key for this table.

Comment: It seems `last_purchase_created_ts` of first row of your expected output should be 1 rather than 2 or am I missing something?

Comment: @TomášZáluský Indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with p as (
    select *, lead(created_ts) over (partition by user_id order by created_ts) as nextts
    from messages where type = 'purchase'
)
select *
from messages s
left outer join p on p.user_id = s.user_id
    and s.created_ts >= p.created_ts and (s.created_ts < p.nextts or p.nextts is null)
where s.type = 'support'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aea646e85dfa35896f8cacfabec439d6

Comment: Nice solution, I corrected underscores and small syntax errors. I hope I didn't misunderstand your intention. I really like it.

Comment: Thank you! This works twice as fast as mine.

Comment: BTW, what would be the difference if we moved the condition `(s.created_ts between p.created_ts and p.nextts or p.nextts is null)` from the `join` clause to the last `where` clause?

Comment: @dimid Actually that null check was potentially buggy. The difference is that not having the condition in the join would allow for a situation where the only purchase occurred after the support message so it gets dropped. I don't know if that's supposed to be possible. Logically it's part of the join condition so I would argue it belongs there regardless. See update above.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for your problem is double usage of window functions. First use `count` function to identify bounds of groups where each group starts with `purchase` and continues with all subsequent `support`s. Then use `max` function to get (actually single nonnull) value among each group.

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5fd2d5f2c841e3e2d412cc3bf723e6a5) is for Postgres but uses only standard SQL, I hope it will be usable for Redshift too.

```sql
with messages(msg_id,   user_id,    created_ts,     type) as (values
(1,     1,  1,  'purchase'),
(2,     1,  2,  'support'),
(3,     2,  3,  'purchase'),
(4,     2,  4,  'support'),
(5,     2,  5,  'support')
)
, precomputed as (
  select m.*
       , case m.type when 'purchase' then m.msg_id end as last_purchase_msg_id
       , case m.type when 'purchase' then m.created_ts end as last_purchase_created_ts
       , count(case m.type when 'purchase' then 1 end) over (order by m.created_ts) as grp
  from messages m
)
, lasts as (
  select g.msg_id, g.user_id, g.created_ts, g.type
       , max(g.last_purchase_msg_id) over (partition by g.grp) as last_purchase_msg_id
       , max(g.last_purchase_created_ts) over (partition by g.grp) as last_purchase_created_ts
  from precomputed g
)
select * from lasts
where type = 'support'
```

Comment: It does assume that message ids increase with time.

Comment: @shawnt00 good point, `over order by` clause corrected

Comment: You'll still have it implied by using `max` too. Perhaps it doesn't matter. I just wanted to make the note.

Comment: `max` does not harm since there is exactly one nonnull value. It could be `min` as well.

Comment: You're right of course about the single value per `grp`.